# Group query upon nested object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking at performing a group by upon a given value within a nest object. For example, my document structure is as follows:

```
{ 
  "ip_address": "192.168.132.12",
  "timestamp" : "2014-08-28T06:41:24",
  "response" : 200,
  "uri": {
     "term": "value A",
     "page" : "1",
     "category" : "category 1"
  }
}
```

What I am looking at achieving is performing a group aggregate upon the `uri.term` field. I know how this is achieved for a direct field, e.g. `"ip_address"`:

```
db.search_stb.aggregate({ $group : {_id : "$ip_address", total : { $sum : 1 }} });
```

but I'm completely stuck on how to do this for the nested object.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try {_id: "$uri.term"} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the '.' operator as follows:

```
db.search_stb.aggregate({ $group : {_id : "$uri.term", total : { $sum : 1 }} });
```

Comment: thanks - I feel really stupid as it was such a simple answer! Another question, as the `uri.term` is optional, how do I get the aggregate to exclude or ignore null values?

Comment: Np, exclude not null would be another question, check questions with the same tag , you will surely find the right answer.. :) Accept the answer if it useful so that it will act as a reference for others.